# HMAC python differs from HMAC php

Tags: php, python, hash, hmac

Im migrating my lumen code to python, for hmac function I have this:

*PHP*

```
$hash = hash_hmac(
  'sha256',
  'user@email.com', 
  'message'
);
```

*Python 3*

```
import hmac
import hashlib

user_hash = hmac.new(b'user@email.com', b'message', hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

The problem is that both results doesnt match:

*PHP Output*

```
413777aac2561ca3acd6d49c95df9ecae4c6e2f6bc9adc40bbb77650d7b4c459
```

*Python Output*

```
42879f50e909799d93b835a81a65c03cf78a56ef1c038ac75c8ab3f211d083ea
```

I guess the problem is how python 3 interpret string but I cant figure it out. Any help please?

Comment: What is your secret and what your text? If you switch `user@email.com` and `message`, the output will be the same as with python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of arguments to HMAC makes a difference:

```
>>> hmac.new(b'user@email.com', b'message', hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
'42879f50e909799d93b835a81a65c03cf78a56ef1c038ac75c8ab3f211d083ea'

>>> hmac.new(b'message', b'user@email.com', hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
'413777aac2561ca3acd6d49c95df9ecae4c6e2f6bc9adc40bbb77650d7b4c459'
```

In `hmac.new`, the first argument is the `key` (the starting key for the hash), and the second argument is the `msg`, the message to be digested.